# LESS - Replacing a variable inside the CSS

Tags: css, less

I have this `LESS` code which takes lengths from 3 to 25. However should inputs will be like `5.1` or `6.2` and such. In the `LESS` CSS, I want it so that instead of `length5.1char` .. it is `length5-1char`... as to replace the dot with the hypen.

Here is my code:

```
<h2>5.1</h2>
<div class="length5-1chars">
  Width...
</div>
<p>The above bar should be much, much shorter.</p>
<h2>20</h2>
<div class="length20chars">
  Hello
</div>
<h2>15</h2>
<div class="length15chars">
  Hello
</div>
<h2>10</h2>
<div class="length10chars">
  Hello
</div>
```

LESS:

```
@fieldLengths: 3, 4, 5, 5.1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 25;

// mixin to iterate over colors and create CSS class for each one
.make-field-lengths(@i: length(@fieldLengths)) when (@i > 0) {
    .make-field-lengths(@i - 1);
    @fieldLength: extract(@fieldLengths, @i); 
    @name: replace(~"@{fieldLength}", "/^\d+\.\d+$/i", "-");
    .length@{name}chars {
        @newWidth:  floor(@fieldLength * 7 + 10);
        width: ~"@{newWidth}px";
      }
}

.make-field-lengths();

div {
  background: #cacaca;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-down: 15px;
}
```

LIVE DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKJqyM

If you go to the CSS tab and view the **compiled version**, you will see that it *still* says `.length5.1chars` when it SHOULD say `.length5-1chars`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I replaced:

`@name: replace(~"@{fieldLength}", "/^\d+\.\d+$/i", "-");`

with this:

```
@name: ~`"@{fieldLength}".replace(/\./i, '-')`;
```

It worked because that is the appropriate syntax when LESS variables are involved with conflicting characters.

Comment: Just `replace(~"@{field-length}", "\.", -);` should be [enough](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40field-length%3A%205.1%3B%5Cn%40name%3A%20replace(~%5C%22%40%7Bfield-length%7D%5C%22%2C%20%5C%22%5C%5C.%5C%22%2C%20-)%3B%5Cn%5Cn%40%7Bname%7D%20%7B-%3A-%7D%22%7D).